# Why do I get a 404 error from the "boost-latest" PPA on 11.04?

Tags: apt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I fix a 404 Error using a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa)

I followed [boost-latest](https://launchpad.net/~boost-latest/+archive/ppa) webpage.

I use ubuntu 11.04(natty).

I add repository success:

```
  sam@sam:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:boost-latest/ppa
  Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --secret-keyring /etc/apt/secring.gpg --trustdb-name /etc/apt/trustdb.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80/ --recv D9CFF117BD794DCE7C080E310CFB84AE029DB5C7
  gpg: requesting key 029DB5C7 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
  gpg: key 029DB5C7: "Launchpad boost-latest" not changed
  gpg: Total number processed: 1
  gpg:              unchanged: 1
  sam@sam:~$
```

But when I apt-get update, it shows the error:

```
  sam@sam:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ sudo apt-get update
  Ign http://packages.ros.org natty InRelease
  Ign http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com natty InRelease                                              
  Ign http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates InRelease                                      
  Hit http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com natty Release.gpg                                            
  Hit http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates Release.gpg                                    
  Hit http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com natty Release                                                
  Hit http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates Release                                        
  Ign http://linux.dropbox.com natty InRelease                                                  
  Hit http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com natty/main Sources                                           
  Hit http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com natty/restricted Sources                                     
  Hit http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com natty/universe Sources                                       
  Hit http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com natty/multiverse Sources                                     
  Hit http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com natty/main amd64 Packages                                    
  Hit http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com natty/restricted amd64 Packages                              
  Hit http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com natty/universe amd64 Packages                                
  Hit http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com natty/multiverse amd64 Packages                              
  Ign http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com natty/main TranslationIndex                                  
  Ign http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com natty/multiverse TranslationIndex                            
  Ign http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com natty/restricted TranslationIndex                            
  Ign http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com natty/universe TranslationIndex                              
  Hit http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/main Sources                                   
  Hit http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/restricted Sources                             
  Hit http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/universe Sources                               
  Hit http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/multiverse Sources                             
  Hit http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/main amd64 Packages                            
  Hit http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages                      
  Hit http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/universe amd64 Packages                        
  Hit http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages                      
  Ign http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/main TranslationIndex                          
  Ign http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex                    
  Ign http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/restricted TranslationIndex                    
  Ign http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/universe TranslationIndex                      
  Hit http://packages.ros.org natty Release.gpg                                                 
  Ign http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com natty/main Translation-en                                    
  Ign http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com natty/multiverse Translation-en                              
  Ign http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com natty/restricted Translation-en                              
  Ign http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com natty/universe Translation-en                                
  Ign http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/main Translation-en                            
  Ign http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/multiverse Translation-en                      
  Ign http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/restricted Translation-en                      
  Ign http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/universe Translation-en                        
  Hit http://linux.dropbox.com natty Release.gpg                                                
  Hit http://packages.ros.org natty Release                                                     
  Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com natty InRelease                                                  
  Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty InRelease                                                  
  Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty InRelease                                               
  Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty InRelease                                                  
  Hit http://packages.ros.org natty/main amd64 Packages                                         
  Hit http://linux.dropbox.com natty Release                                                    
  Ign http://packages.ros.org natty/main TranslationIndex                                       
  Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com natty Release.gpg                                             
  Ign http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security InRelease                                    
  Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty InRelease                                               
  Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty InRelease                                               
  Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty InRelease                                               
  Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty Release.gpg                                                
  Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty Release.gpg                                                
  Hit http://linux.dropbox.com natty/main amd64 Packages                                        
  Ign http://linux.dropbox.com natty/main TranslationIndex                                      
  Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com natty Release                                                 
  Hit http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security Release.gpg                                     
  Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty Release.gpg                                                
  Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty Release.gpg                                             
  Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty Release.gpg                                             
  Hit http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security Release                                         
  Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com natty/main Sources                                               
  Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty Release.gpg                                                
  Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty Release                                                    
  Ign http://packages.ros.org natty/main Translation-en                                         
  Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com natty/main amd64 Packages                                        
  Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com natty/main TranslationIndex                                   
  Hit http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/main Sources                                 
  Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty Release                           
  Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty Release                           
  Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty Release                           
  Ign http://linux.dropbox.com natty/main Translation-en                                        
  Hit http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/restricted Sources                           
  Hit http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/universe Sources       
  Hit http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/multiverse Sources     
  Hit http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/main amd64 Packages    
  Hit http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/restricted amd64 Packages
  Hit http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/universe amd64 Packages
  Hit http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
  Ign http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/main TranslationIndex  
  Ign http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/multiverse TranslationIndex
  Ign http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/restricted TranslationIndex
  Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty Release                           
  Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty Release                           
  Ign http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/universe TranslationIndex                    
  Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main TranslationIndex             
  Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main Sources                      
  Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main amd64 Packages               
  Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main TranslationIndex             
  Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main Sources                      
  Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main amd64 Packages               
  Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main TranslationIndex             
  Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main Sources                      
  Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main amd64 Packages               
  Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main TranslationIndex             
  Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main Sources                      
  Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main amd64 Packages               
  Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main TranslationIndex             
  Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main Sources                      
  Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main amd64 Packages               
  Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main TranslationIndex             
  Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com natty/main Translation-en               
  Err http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main Sources                      
    404  Not Found
  Err http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main amd64 Packages
    404  Not Found
  Ign http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/main Translation-en
  Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main Translation-en
  Ign http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/multiverse Translation-en
  Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main Translation-en
  Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main Translation-en
  Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main Translation-en
  Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main Translation-en
  Ign http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/restricted Translation-en
  Ign http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/universe Translation-en
  Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main Translation-en
  W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/boost-latest/ppa/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

  W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/boost-latest/ppa/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

  E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
  sam@sam:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$
```

My update sources pic:

[image]

My /etc/apt/sources.list.d directory:

```
  sam@sam:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ ls
  boost-latest-ppa-natty.list       openrave-release-natty.list.save
  bumblebee-stable-natty.list       ros-latest.list
  bumblebee-stable-natty.list.save  ros-latest.list.save
  dropbox.list                      tim-klingt-ppa-natty.list
  dropbox.list.save                 tim-klingt-ppa-natty.list.save
  gummi-gummi-natty.list            v-launchpad-jochen-sprickerhof-de-pcl-natty.list
  gummi-gummi-natty.list.save       v-launchpad-jochen-sprickerhof-de-pcl-natty.list.save
  openrave-release-natty.list
  sam@sam:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$
```

And my sources.list:

```
  sam@sam:/etc/apt$ cat sources.list
  # deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 11.04 _Natty Narwhal_ - Release amd64 (20110427.1)]/ natty main restricted

  # See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
  # newer versions of the distribution.
  deb http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty main restricted
  deb-src http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty main restricted

  ## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
  ## distribution.
  deb http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates main restricted
  deb-src http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates main restricted

  ## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
  ## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
  ## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
  deb http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty universe
  deb-src http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty universe
  deb http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates universe
  deb-src http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates universe

  ## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
  ## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
  ## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
  ## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
  ## security team.
  deb http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty multiverse
  deb-src http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty multiverse
  deb http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates multiverse
  deb-src http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates multiverse

  ## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from the 'backports'
  ## repository.
  ## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
  ## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
  ## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
  ## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
  ## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
  # deb http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
  # deb-src http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

  deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty-security main restricted
  deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty-security main restricted
  deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty-security universe
  deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty-security universe
  deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty-security multiverse
  deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty-security multiverse

  ## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
  ## 'partner' repository.
  ## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
  ## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
  # deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu natty partner
  # deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu natty partner

  ## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
  ## developers who want to ship their latest software.
  deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty main
  deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty main
  sam@sam:/etc/apt$
```

How to solve it?

Thank you~

Comment: Try changing your Mirror from Software Sources

Comment: It's not the same question,because I want to install boost but 404 happened unfortunately, not just remove the repository which disappeared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That PPA appears to be obsolete and hasn't been updated since 2010. The 404 error is expected since [the latest Ubuntu the PPA provides packages for is 10.10 Maverick](https://launchpad.net/~boost-latest/+archive/ppa).

Please consider using the Boost libraries provided in the official repositories. If you need a newer version, you can try finding another ppa or building from source OR possibly upgrading your Ubuntu.